# Changed Product Name but IPA stays same

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I edited an app to change name completely.  I successfully changed the Project Name and display name, but as you can see in the picture, the IPA name stays the same.  Is there a way to change this, or does it matter?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode-> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Manage Schemes -> Click on the name to rename

Comment: Thanks.  Is it necessary to have them all named same, or will I be fine with what I had already submitted?

Comment: No need to have it same, it is just your build scheme. target is what you set for the build process. Scheme is with which configuration you will have the build.